# How can I speed up looping through pixels in an image?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, loops, opencv, python

I am working with images as numpy arrays. I have a mask and I am editing the picture based on the mask (also an array). Presently, I am looping through each pixel and changing a the corresponding pixel in a white image the the values of the original image (in the case called cropped array). It seems like there should be a way to say something like white1=cropped array where mask==True. I thought that may speed this process up since I am working with so many images. Is this possible? I will try to make a simple example.

```
mask=[[True,True,False,False],[True,True,True,True]]
white1=[[[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255]],[[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255]]]
cropped_array=[[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17]],[[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17]]]
h , w = mask.shape
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if mask[i][j]==True:
           white1[i][j] = cropped_array[i][j]
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible using boolean masking, but if you want fast answers, please post a reproducible and minimal code. You can create a couple of small dummy arrays to better specify what exactly your problem is. Take a look at guidelines for asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively choose elements by simply multiplying with the mask.

```
import numpy as np

mask=[[True,True,False,False],[True,True,True,True]]
white1=[[[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255]],[[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255]]]
cropped_array=[[[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17]],[[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17],[110,200,17]]]

mask = np.array(mask)
white1 = np.array(white1)
cropped_array = np.array(cropped_array)

h , w = mask.shape
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if mask[i][j]==True:
           white1[i][j] = cropped_array[i][j]

white = (cropped_array * mask[..., None]) + (white1 * ~mask[..., None])

print(np.allclose(white, white1))
```

Gives `True`